# Groovy RPC & Magento API: product_attribute.create & Invalid request parameters

Tags: xml, magento, grails, groovy, rpc

I would like to use XML-RPC API from Magento (1.9) with Groovy and am able to connect and login.

This works fine:

```
def api = new XMLRPCServerProxy("http://magentourl/api/xmlrpc", true)
api.login("user", "key")
return api.call(key, "catalog_product.list")
```

Event this works:

```
api.call(key, "product_attribute.info", [132])
```

But I'm having troubles adding a new product attribute:

```
def code = "myattribute-unique"
def frontendInput = "text"
def scope = "global"
def defaultValue = "default-Value"
int unique = 1
int required = 1
String[] applyTo = ["simple", "grouped"].toArray()
int configurable = 1
int searchable = 1
int visibleAdvancedSearch = 1
int comparable = 1
int usedPromoRules = 1
int visibleOnFront = 1
int usedProductListing = 1
def additionalFields = ["frontend_class": "validate-email", "is_html_allowed_on_front": true, "used_for_sort_by": true]
def frontendLabel = [[0, "frontend-label1"], [1, "frontend-label2"]].toArray()    
def array = [code, frontendInput, scope, defaultValue, unique, required, applyTo, configurable, searchable, visibleAdvancedSearch, comparable, usedPromoRules, visibleOnFront, usedProductListing, additionalFields, frontendLabel]    

def result = api.call(key, "product_attribute.create", array)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Class uk.co.wilson.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCFailException
Message Invalid request parameters.
```

I tried to initialize the attributes as Array instead just the Groovy-dynamic def-way, but with no luck.

What can I do to proceed or what helps me debugging?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it works when proceeding with a map and keys:

```
def code = "a_select_1"
def frontendInput = "select"

def array = [**attribute_code**: code, frontend_input: frontendInput, scope: scope, default_value: defaultValue, is_unique: unique, is_required: required, apply_to: applyTo, is_configurable: configurable, is_searchable: searchable, is_visible_in_advanced_search: visibleAdvancedSearch, is_comparable: comparable, is_used_for_promo_rules: usedPromoRules, is_visible_on_front: visibleOnFront, used_in_product_listing: usedProductListing, additional_fields: additionalFields, frontend_label: frontendLabel]
```